# Mongodb authentication inside a docker container

Tags: mongodb, docker, authentication, server

This is my situation. I have a mongodb docker container instance and i need to change the admin password. Now, I have the credentials to connect to the mongodb just fine, using the host and ip and the credentials. I have access to the server via ssh and I need to change the admin password. But if i do,

```
mongo manager --port 27017 -u "admin" -p "--------"
--authenticationDatabase "manager"
```

Gives me an authentication error. And i cannot run any administration commands such as: db.auth('admin', 'password')

My question is how can i stop mongo inside the container if i do?

```
docker exec -it mongodb bash
```

Any other workaround will work. The goal is the change the password or create a new admin user to control the users and roles.

Thank you so much for the help. Please let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure your authenticationDatabase is "manager"?

In anyway, you don't need to stop mongo proces to interact with database but authenticate a user with necessary privileges using mongo shell.

1. Get access to running mongo container:

   $ docker exec -it «container_name» bash
2. Authenticate using mongo shell:

   $ mongo -u admin -p 123admin --authenticationDatabase admin
3. Once you authenticated, run shell script to switch to database that holds user's data.

   $ use admin
4. Run changeUserPassword command to change password:

   $ db.changeUserPassword("admin", "admin123")

Thats it.

Comment: Thank you for answering! The database authentication was admin.